# Nested list after json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get all the data out of an API call which is returned in the json format.

For this purpose I'm using the json_normalize library from pandas, but I'm left with a list within that list that is not unwrapped.

This is the code I am using:

```
data=requests.get(url,endpointParams)
data_read=json.loads(data.content)
values=json_normalize(data_read['data'])
```

This is what I end up with:

| name | period | values | title | description | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| follower_count | day | [{'value': 0, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}] | Follower Count | Total number of unique accounts following this profile | 1/insights/follower_count/day |
| impressions | day | [{'value': 19100, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 6000, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}] | Impressions | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been viewed | 1/insights/impressions/day |
| profile_views | day | [{'value': 80, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 90, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}] | Profile Views | Total number of users who have viewed the Business Account's profile within the specified period | 1/insights/profile_views/day |
| reach | day | [{'value': 5000, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 2000, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}] | Reach | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been uniquely viewed | 1/insights/reach/day |

My question is how do I unwrap the **values** column?

EDIT: Here's the **data_read** before normalizing:

```
{'data': [{'name': 'follower_count',
   'period': 'day',
   'values': [{'value': 50, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'},
    {'value': 50, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}],
   'title': 'Follower Count',
   'description': 'Total number of unique accounts following this profile',
   'id': '1/insights/follower_count/day'},
  {'name': 'impressions',
   'period': 'day',
   'values': [{'value': 19000, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'},
    {'value': 6000, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}],
   'title': 'Impressions',
   'description': "Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been viewed",
   'id': '1/insights/impressions/day'},
  {'name': 'profile_views',
   'period': 'day',
   'values': [{'value': 90, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'},
    {'value': 99, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}],
   'title': 'Profile Views',
   'description': "Total number of users who have viewed the Business Account's profile within the specified period",
   'id': '1/insights/profile_views/day'},
  {'name': 'reach',
   'period': 'day',
   'values': [{'value': 5000, 'end_time': '2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000'},
    {'value': 2000, 'end_time': '2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000'}],
   'title': 'Reach',
   'description': "Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been uniquely viewed",
   'id': '1/insights/reach/day'}],
 'paging': {'previous': 'someotherurl.com',
  'next': 'someurl.com'}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data_read`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
metadata = ['name', 'period', 'title', 'description', 'id']
out = pd.json_normalize(data_read['data'], 'values', metadata)
```

| value | end_time | name | period | title | description | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000 | follower_count | day | Follower Count | Total number of unique accounts following this profile | 1/insights/follower_count/day |
| 50 | 2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000 | follower_count | day | Follower Count | Total number of unique accounts following this profile | 1/insights/follower_count/day |
| 19000 | 2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000 | impressions | day | Impressions | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been viewed | 1/insights/impressions/day |
| 6000 | 2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000 | impressions | day | Impressions | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been viewed | 1/insights/impressions/day |
| 90 | 2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000 | profile_views | day | Profile Views | Total number of users who have viewed the Business Account's profile within the specified period | 1/insights/profile_views/day |
| 99 | 2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000 | profile_views | day | Profile Views | Total number of users who have viewed the Business Account's profile within the specified period | 1/insights/profile_views/day |
| 5000 | 2022-03-27T07:00:00+0000 | reach | day | Reach | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been uniquely viewed | 1/insights/reach/day |
| 2000 | 2022-03-28T07:00:00+0000 | reach | day | Reach | Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been uniquely viewed | 1/insights/reach/day |

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works. I've been reading up on the json_normalize but I can't understand how this solution works - could you just briefly explain the logic of it? Thanks so much

Comment: The third parameter of `pd.json_normalize` is the columns to be used as metadata (the outer level). So you extract all rows in `values` and set other fields as metadata.

Comment: master of the json_normalize :p

Comment: @Corralien How would you do this without having to list the column names in "metadata"? I have a json with 30+ fields so looking for a method where I won't have to write each column name individually

Comment: @Mitch. It depends on your data structure. For example, you can take the first record of your data and use `set` operations to build dynamically the metadata list.